# Regex - how to match two or four same letters but not three

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have input string of:

```
"some random text RR some Text RRR RRRR"
```

and what I need is to match only double R or quadruple R BUT NOT triple R. How would I do that using a regular expression?

EDIT:
what if the input string is "somerandomtextRRsomeTextRRRanytextRRRRanytext" and I want only match double or quadruple R?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
(?<!R)(?:R{2})+(?!R)
```

#### Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/eW7lX0

**EDIT:** For Javascript use:

```
(?:^|[^R])((?:R{2})+)(?!R)
```

Comment: The link I provided has full description of the regex used and I though it is better if I don't duplicate the content again.

Comment: A large proportion of Stack Overflow contains content from other sources, it's about making your answer self-contained. A link is useful but not sufficient to make a complete answer.

Comment: What if the string was "somerandomtextRRsomeTextRRRanytextRRRR"? Unfortunatly I cannot use word boundaries.

Comment: @anubhava Is it also possible to make it work in javascript? Unfortunately lookbehind is not supported by javascript.

Comment: @petriq: You're changing nature of the problem. First you changed the example input and now this. May I know if it was Javascript why did you not tag it so?

Comment: @anubhava My bad I did not clearly state my problem, sorry. Anyway your javascript regex also matches one char before RR or RRRR.

Comment: Yes it will since there is no lookbehind. But you should really start paying attention to the details of the answer. Javascript regex has a matching group and inside matching group there is not extra character (shown under Match groups here: http://regex101.com/r/vZ1dL7)